# Tag search in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vuejs2

I've made a search function to show related projects based on chosen tag and I'm getting results with wrong values

## What I've done so far

1. Create controller function and return results as json
2. Create route in `app.js`
3. Create new component to show results
4. made axios request to send data to controller and redirect to new component for results

## Code

`controller`

```php
public function areas(Request $request){
        $areas = Project::where('area', $request->area)->where('published', '=', 'y')->get();
        return response()->json($areas, 200);
    }
```

`route in api.php`

```php
Route::get('areasearch', 'Api\SearchController@areas');
```

`route in app.js`

```js
import AreasPage from './components/areassearch.vue'
{
  path: '/areas',
  name: 'areas',
  props: true,
  component: AreasPage,
},
```

`search script + component link`

```
// link
```

```js
<a v-model.lazy="area" @click="areasearch">{{project.area}}</a>

//script
```

```js
methods: {
        //search in areas
        areasearch() {
            axios.get('/api/areasearch', {
                params: {
                  area: this.area
                }
              })
              .then(response => {

                this.$router.push({
                  name: 'areas',
                  params: {
                    areas: response.data
                  }
                })

              })
              .catch(error => {});
        },
    },
```

`results component`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <navbar></navbar>

    <template v-if="areas.length > 0">
    <div class="container-fluid counters">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div v-for="area in areas" :key="area.id" :to="`/projects/${area.slug}`">
                <li>{{area.title}}</li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <p>Sorry there is no area for you, try search new query.</p>
    </template>

    <footerss></footerss>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    import navbar from './navbar.vue';
    import footerss from './footer.vue';
  export default {
    props: ['areas'],
    components: {
        navbar,
        footerss
    },
  }
</script>
```

## Issue

1. My link is not behave as a link (is like text when i move mouse over it)
2. For example if I search for area `Jakarta` most of results I get is projects where their `area` column is `null`.

Any idea?

Comment: try to see if `$request->area` is null

Comment: @Hussein I `dd` my requests (still i redirected to new page with this in my network response `[]`

Comment: @mafortis, why don't u use something else, like a span or a button instead of an anchor

Comment: @Erubiel anything that works is fine by me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the link part, you are using v-model on an anchors, v-model is mainly for inputs, selects, textareas. So

```
<a v-model.lazy="area" @click="areasearch">{{project.area}}</a>
```

Should be

```
<span class="my-link" @click="areasearch(project.area)">{{project.area}}</span>
```

Use a span, and a class for that span, then on click call your method, i don't know if thats the correct variable for your axios call, btw. it could be project.area.id, or something else...

As for it looking like a link, i assume you are familiar with `cursor:pointer` css rule.

Your axios part should look something like this:

```js
areasearch(thearea) {
    axios.get('/api/areasearch', {
        params: {
            area: thearea
        }
    })
    .then(response => {

        this.$router.push({
            name: 'areas',
            params: {
                areas: response.data
            }
        })

    })
    .catch(error => {});
},
```

As for the controller part:

```php
public function areas(Request $request){

    $auxAreas = explode("+", $request->area);

    $areas = Project::whereNotNull('area')
        ->whereIn('area', $auxAreas)
        ->where('published', '=', 'y')
        ->get();
    return response()->json($areas, 200);
}
```

Comment: where you defined this `thearea`?

Comment: ok it's passing the area now but i get no result error `Sorry there is no area for you, try search new query.` in my results page (v-if). what is passed is: `area All+Indonesia` and this result is same for my function and other function suggested by hussein.

Comment: right. (i figure something) if i search for single word `e.g. area: depok` it shows results but if for multiple words `e.g. area: All+Indonesia` it gives error.

Comment: in response json part is deactive and playload just shows `[]`

Comment: for which part? `whereIn`

Comment: that was my bad (last comment) sorry. It's working perfectly

Comment: Yeah, i was gonna suggest it was your data set... no problemo my friend!

Answer (score 0):

first for the wrong result issue try this:

```
public function areas(Request $request){
 $areas = Project::whereNotNull('area')
 ->where([
    ['area', $request->area],
    ['published', '=', 'y']
 ])->get();
 return response()->json($areas, 200);
}
```

Comment: what doesn't have a tag?

Comment: i think this `{{project.area}}` won't pass to axios currently i need somehow get this value

Comment: sorry my bad thought you are talking about an item `<i></i>`

Comment: `$request->area` comes as null in controller so i think it is not passing to controller.

Comment: well just add request rules, then you can verify that it exists and have a value, if so then the issue in vue.js

Comment: the thing is this link works only if area is exist (so user can see the area in view and is able to click it) otherwise there is no link to click **which means rule even if not provided is always true**

Comment: is behaving exactly as post tags (if post has tag you can click and see all posts including that tag if post doesn't have tag there is nothing to click)